# QGIS File Geodatabase Vertices missing

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase

I am adding Data from a File Geodatabase to QGIS. Everything is working fine, but the drawing of a specific Line subtyp (first image).
It looks like, QGIS can not draw the circle properly. An export to shape (second image) and adding to Qgis shows how the feature should be drawn.

Anybody seen something similar and a solution?

[image: Data from the FGDB]

[image: The same as ShapeShape]

Comment: It looks to me like that segment is a true arc and for whatever reason QGIS either isn't or can't draw true curves, or at least not that one for some reason. Shapefiles do not support true curves, so they're converted into many little line segments to approximate the curve. This is clear from the number of nodes/vertices visible in your two screenshots. It doesn't seem to have a problem with the rounded 'street end' though. I'm not sure if it would be a bug in QGIS rendering, reading of the FGDB, or a geometry error in the FGDB itself. What version of QGIS and any relevant plugins?

Comment: I tested this in 2.8 and 2.9 with the same result. I think you are right. The affected segments where created with the "Circle tool" wich creates true arcs. The rounded street is buffered from the center line. Looks like QGIS can't draw true curves stored in FGDB.

Comment: Related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139441/