# QGIS Renders Buffer Polygons from ArcGIS Feature Class Differently

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, buffer

I have a polygon feature class stored in an ArcGIS geodatabase. All of the shapes are buffers of a point layer created using the editor menu's 'Buffer' command. In ArcMap 10.3.1 the data looks like this:

[image]

Using the ESRI FileGDB driver, I can bring the data into QGIS (tried on 2.8.6 and 2.8.14). However, the drawing of the buffers is completely different:
[image]
I understand there may be implementation differences that cause this and I probably can't do much about it. What I'm really interested in is if someone knows what accounts for the difference in rendering of circular polygons between ArcGIS and QGIS, or could point me somewhere (ogr documentation? Qgis documentation?) where I might figure this out.

Comment: Do the buffers use ARCS/CURVES instead of regular linestrings? The openfilegdb and esri filegdb api driver both don't support curves in geometries unfortunately. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139441/qgis-2-8-1-openfilegdb-compatibility-with-esri-filegdb#comment202428_139522

Comment: @SaultDon  I think you should post your comment as an answer

Comment: A better looking result in QGIS is to convert the feature class to a shapefile in ArcGIS (not QGIS) and then use that in QGIS.  ArcGIS adds the necessary vertices to make them look similar.  Alternately one can use the buffer wizard in ArcGIS to create the buffers in a file geodatabase feature class since it will not create true curves.  This is what I do whenever possible since I hate true curves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paraphrasing a comment by @SaultDon:

> If the buffers use ARCS/CURVES instead of regular linestrings, then be
>   aware that the openfilegdb and esri filegdb api driver both don't
>   support curves in geometries unfortunately. See
>   [QGIS 2.8.1 OpenFileGDB compatibility with ESRI FileGDB?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139441/qgis-2-8-1-openfilegdb-compatibility-with-esri-filegdb#comment202428_139522)